# how to display many legends for chart on the image

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, jcchart

I have to show all the legends created for the chart on the image when converting the chart into image.but the number of legends are much due to which the the legends are cut from the bottom and only few legends appear on the image.

So please can any body tell me how solve this problem

Comment: What version of JFreeChart? Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create image of chart for JCChart I use snapshot(JCChart,int) method of JCChart, it will return the image of the chart. So to display all the legends we will have to overide the snapshot method as follows

public Image snapshot(JCChart chart,int num_legends){
      Image image = chart.createImage(chart.getSize().width, chart.getSize().height+
                        (chart.getLegend().getSymbolSize()+4)*num_legends);
      if(image != null)
      {
           Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
           g.setClip(0, 0, chart.getSize().width,
        chart.getSize().height+chart.getSize().height+
 (chart.getLegend().getSymbolSize()+4)*num_legends);
                chart.paint(g);
            }
            return image;
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a chart into an image like this:

```
OutputStream out = ...
org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out, chart, width, height, null, true, 0);
```

Is that the method you're using?

Comment: actually I am using the jcchart and when the chart is ploated then if ithere are to many legends than only those legens which fit till the size of chart display and rest reagio is discarded

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you are doing, could you post the code or at least a screenshot?